# Map with functions JavaScript style in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm a C++ programar with some experience with JavaScript. I would like to do in C++11 something similar to this code:

```
map = {
    "text1": function() { /*function #1 code*/ },
    // ..
    "textn": function() { /*function #n code*/ }
 }
```

I'm aware they have added lambdas in C++11, but I'm not sure how to use them from my specific purpose.

**EDIT:**

The classical way to implement this in C/C++ is via Function Pointer Arrays, but I find them really hard to debug

Comment: a map of string and `std::function`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
#include <functional>
std::map<std::string, std::function<void()>> myMap {
    { "text1", []() { /*function #1 code*/ } },
    //...
    { "textn", []() { /*function #n code*/ } }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

@Stefano gave you correct data type for the problem. Though I would like to show some details:

First of all, you cannot use `key:value` syntax. You'll need to do something like this:

```
std::map<std::string, std::function<void()>> myMap{
    {"key", /*any callable, including lambdas, functions and function objects*/},
    //ditto
};
```

Do note that they all must have the same function signature, e.g. in this case return type must be `void`, and it shouldn't accept any arguments.